# Ending Loop on Pressing the Escape Button

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a question regarding a DS&OOP assignment that we had, earlier this semester. One of the questions was to simulate a car toll booth at a bridge where you had to keep track of 1) Cars passing by 2) Cars that paid the toll and 3) Total number of cars passed by and total cash collected. User had to press 'p' for paying car, 'n' for non-paying car, and pressing the escape button (esc) had to end the code and print out the total number of cars passed by and money collected. I did this part of the code using a while loop that looked like this:

```
int main()
{
    tollBooth t;
    char c = 0;
    while (c != 'e' && c != 'E')
    {
        cout << "Choose:\n'p' paying car \n'n' nonpaying car \n'e' exit \n";
        cin >> c;
        switch (c) {
        case 'p':
        case 'P':
            t.payingCar();
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            t.nopayCar();
            break;
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid choice, try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    } 
    t.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to end the code on pressing the escape button so I just chose the letter E instead of the esc button. But if I was to do it using the escape button, what changes would be needed in the code?

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, I got your back!

So, to resolve this problem we use " _getch() " function which is typically found in the " <conio.h> " header file.

The ASCII code for the Escape key is 27. When you press the Escape key, it generates an ASCII value of 27.Therefore, I'll slightly alter your program to get your desired outcome:

```
    int main()
{
    tollBooth t;
    char key;

    while (key != 27)
    {   
        key = _getch();
        cout << "Choose:\n'p' paying car \n'n' nonpaying car \n'e' exit \n";
        if (key != 27)
            cout << key << endl;
        if (key == 'p')
            t.payingCar();
        else if (key == 'n')
            t.nopayCar();
        else if (key != 27)
            cout << "Invalid input"<<endl;
    }

    t.display();

    return 0;
}
```

In the above program I've used "key" instead of "c" for better understanding.

Comment: There's nothing in the problem statement that says that the console uses ASCII. Chances are that it does, but be aware that that's an assumption, not a requirement.

Comment: Also, `_getch()` is not standard C++; it's a Microsoft thing, so, again, not portable.

Comment: Sadly, there is still no standard way of waiting for keyboard press in C++. Thus, assuming a console is used to runi the program something like `_getch()` or some UNIX specific approach (e.g., setting the console parameters) will be needed. GUI frameworks will have their own approach.

Comment: In *standard* C++, one would use `Ctrl-Z` or similar (depending on your platform) to stop input. You can then use `cin` normally, and just validate that each input operation succeeds (using `cin.good()`/`cin.fail()`, or `cin.operator bool`/`operator!`, etc)